# I want to know solution of Paypal issue: "REQUIRED to avoid service interruption you need to complete important security"

Tags: paypal

I'm confused that what that means. I request you please let me know solution of this PayPal error. I got this message today

"REQUIRED to avoid service interruption you need to complete important security"

Thank You ..

Comment: Is this an API question or a general user question? Is this message in your API implementation? An email you received? [Paypal security requirements notice](https://www.paypal-notice.com/en/TLS-1.2-and-HTTP1.1-Upgrade/) have been out for at least a **year**.

Answer (score 0):

if your account is business give your tax id and complete info in your account ok

Comment: Paypal Message it that:- Our records indicate that you still need to make critical security upgrades to your systems. If you see a “YES” next to a security change, your integration must be updated to accept these new security measures as soon as possible.

Answer (score 0):

I think your webpages are not secure or you provide vulnerable information to pay-pal.